# Which screen type should I use for Android Tablet with same resolution and varying size/inches?

Tags: android

The case:
Tablet-01:
Screen size: 7 inches
Resolution: 1280x800

Tablet-02:
Screen size: 8 inches
Resolution: 1280x800

Tablet-03:
Screen size: 10 inches
Resolution: 1280x800

In application this gives me display type as "LargeScreen" with sw600 dpi category.  But my application renders the UI/contents differently on all the screens.

Since the resolution and display type is same all across sizes (7", 8" & 10"), can I achieve the similar/same contents on each of the screen/display? And how?

Comment: It looks like all the tablets have the same screen size.

Comment: They probably have different software DPI values set. Android bases layout matches on the software density, not the hardware density.